# OpenSuse/KDE auto Move To/Copy To?

Tags: kde, opensuse

I'm on a fresh install of OpenSuse and this is also my first contact with KDE. I find it odd that by default, everytime I try and drag and drop a file or folder, I get asked if I want to Move them to that location or Copy them.

Is there a way to set this to the standard defaults (copy when moving to another device, move when on the same device)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There's no way to change this. It's built into Dolphin.